# C++ Is there any good methods to binding property with WinAPI control?

Tags: c++, wpf, winapi, binding

I'm new to `WinAPI`. I maked programs just `WPF` and `WinForm`

In `C++` with `WinAPI`, I want to bind data like a `WPF`

What is a great method (or library) for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not clear what your looking for, `SetProp()` et al are available to store arbitrary handles against a HWND

Answer (score -1):

One of the easiest way is to use a pointer to a private data structure and to store this pointer with SetWindowLongPtr in GWL_USERDATA.

You can Access the data block from anywhere with the window handle and GetWindowLongPtr.

You are responsible to allocate and free this data block.

Comment: Prefer SetWindowLongPtr if you may potentially support 64 bit version.

Comment: `GWL_USERDATA` is owned by the code that called `RegisterClassEx`. It does not belong to client code. If your code registered the window class, you should allocate `cbWndExtra` in the private window memory instead, since bad advice to mindlessly use `GWL_USERDATA` is fairly common. A solution that always works, regardless of who owns the per-window data, is available through [`SetProp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx).